# What would happen if one were to apply for the same (German student) visa from several German embassies in different countries simultaneously?

Tags: visa, germany, student-visa

It is a known fact that German student visa applications can take several months to be resulted in, so it is a long procedure, and it is especially hard to get visa if the embassy in your country is closed right now due to the pandemic.

Say, you applied for a German student visa from an embassy today, and then two weeks later, you went to another embassy in another country (where you have a residence permit) and applied for the same (Germany student) visa.

What would happen then? Would they process the same visa application simultaneously and (if successful) issue the same visa? Would the foreign office reject both applications due the duplicate applications? or something else?

Has anyone tried?

Comment: Since visa applications are entered into a central application, it would be noticed that an existing application exists and thus be rejected. They *may* check if the applications differ. Since visas should be applied for at the main place of residence, applying from **another** main place of residence may effect the original application. Applications that lead to a residence permit are decided in Germany anyway, so this would serve no purpose whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're supposed to apply in the consulate with jurisdiction over your place of residence, the consulate that decides you don't actually reside in its jurisdiction will reject your application.  If you're particularly unlucky, both consulates will come to that conclusion, and then you will be in a difficult situation indeed.